# Validate that string belongs to specific language alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How can I validate Rails model string attribute that it belongs to specific language alphabet characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library called [whatlanguage](http://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage/tree/master) that recognize the languages of the string, example:

```
require 'whatlanguage'
"Je suis un homme".language      # => :french
```

Works with Dutch, English, Farsi, French, German, Swedish, Portuguese, Russian and Spanish out of the box, so it recognize Cyrillic too.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to validate the value of the attribute against a regular expression.

```
# Only match characters a-z
validates_format_of :attr, :with => /[a-z]/
```

Comment: Regular expressions can match any UTF8 encoded characters by including the `u` option. `'你'.match(/你/u) # => #<MatchData:0x5f9970>`

Answer (score 0):

validates_format_of seems to be the right thing for you. [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002168) says:

Validates whether the value of the specified attribute is of the correct form by matching it against the regular expression provided.

```
  class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
  end
```

Note: use \A and \Z to match the start and end of the string, ^ and $ match the start/end of a line.

A regular expression must be provided or else an exception will be raised.